# Можно ли делать perfect forwarding при использовании auto в параметрах функции?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

С С++20 можно использовать т.н. abbreviated шаблоны функций, когда вместо явного имени шаблонного типа мы пишем `auto`. Можно ли (и как) при таком синтаксисе делать perfect forwarding?

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T x); // is equivalent to
void foo(auto x);

template <typename T>
void foo(T&& x) {
  bar(std::forward<T>(x));
} // is equivalent to ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Параметр - `auto &&p`.

Вместо forward - `decltype(p)(p)`. Или `std::forward<decltype(p)>(p)`, результат тот же.

Comment: Можно подробнее, почему `std::forward<T>(x)` в примере эквивалентен `std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)` (ведь в случае ссылки у `x` будет ссылочный тип)?

Comment: @lasqa В первом примере, `T` либо не ссылка, и тогда forward добавляет к нему &&, либо &‐ссылка, тогда тип остается без изменения. Во втором примере `decltype(x)` сразу &- или &&-ссылка. И тот и другой тип `forward` оставляет без изменения и просто кастует к нему, а скастовать можно и руками.